# Linq, how to Group by Field, Sum on Field, First on Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, group-by, linq-to-entities

Hi i'm having a little trouble with the following

I have a table (CallRecords) with an navigation property to another table (ResultCodes)

1. I want to perform a `GroupBy` from (CallRecords) on ResultCodesId
2. `Sum` (The occurrences of ResultCodesId)
3. `First` on an included table and field ResultCodes.Name, I.e the name of the resultCode (via navigation property)

   ```
       var exceptions = Db.CallRecords
           .Include(x => x.ResultCode)
           .Where(x => x.ClientId == id && x.ResultCodeId < 0 && x.StartTime >= startDate && x.StartTime <= finishDate)
           .GroupBy(o => o.ResultCodeId)
           .Select(g => new ExceptionViewModel 
               { 
                   Code = g.Key ?? 0, 
                   Total = g.Count(), 
                   Name = g.First(x => x.ResultCode.Name)

               });
   ```

This is the problem, the following line wont compile

```
Name = g.First(x => x.ResultCode.Name)
```

cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type bool

The answer to this would (seemingly) be fairly simple, however my Google and stack searches are given me back everything except examples i need, so i thought an answer to this might help other unwary travelers

**Update**

Additional Info

View model

```
public class ExceptionViewModel
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Data

```
public class ResultCode
{
    [Required,Key]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class CallRecord
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties removed for brevity

    [Required]
    public int? ResultCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ResultCode ResultCode { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see all properties involved with that problem expression above are of type string, im not sure whether i'm having a brain-fart or there is something i just dont understand

Comment: You forgot to actually mention what trouble you are having exactly.

Comment: Sorry, i've added some more information, that might help

Comment: Do you want to get the name of the result code of the first call record in each group? The syntax for that would be `g.First().ResultCode.Name`.

Comment: The first, i.e the associated name of the result code

Comment: By the way thanks, If you put that in an answer ill mark it, i knew this was something extremely simple

Comment: I added an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `g.First(x => x.ResultCode.Name)` does not do what you think it does. When `First` has an argument that argument is supposed to be a predicate that filters the enumerable sequence.

In other words, `.First(x => ...)` is equivalent to `.Where(x => ...).First()`. If you look at it this way it's clear that `x.ResultCode.Name` is not valid in that context.

What you want is to get the first item in each group and then fish out some data from it. Do that like so:

```
g.First().ResultCode.Name
```